# Why is updated javascript file not executed on a deployed website; asp MVC on azure website

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, azure

I needed to make a little change to my javascript file on my deployed asp mvc website on azure website. So **I redeployed everything and when I open the website and check the resource files, I saw the javascript is changed. Nevertheless, the website behaviour did not seem to change.** It acted just like the old javascript told it to do. What might be the problem, and the solution of it?

**The change works on localhost though.**

Additional Information:

I bundled the javasript through asp MVC bundling system.
Here is the code I changed:

```
$('#welcome-messages ul').bxSlider({
    mode: 'vertical',
    auto: true,
    minSlides: 1,
    responsive: true,
    touchEnabled: true,
    pager: false,
    controls: false,
    useCSS: false,
    pause: 10000 // HERE
});
```

to

```
$('#welcome-messages ul').bxSlider({
    mode: 'vertical',
    auto: true,
    minSlides: 1,
    responsive: true,
    touchEnabled: true,
    pager: false,
    controls: false,
    useCSS: false,
    pause: 3000 // TO HERE
});
```

If you wanna see the minified file that the asp MVC made and attached to the website:

```
$("#welcome-messages ul").bxSlider({mode:"vertical",auto:!0,minSlides:1,responsive:!0,touchEnabled:!0,pager:!1,controls:!1,useCSS:!1,pause:1e3});
```

In summary, I set the PAUSE time for each slide into 3 seconds, from previously 10 seconds. Yet, the website is still behaving 10 seconds pause even though the javasript is changed.

*I also wonder, how can I explore the files that I uploaded to azure website? In other web hosters, they usually have, file manager, or using ftp. Btw, can we also access azure website root folders using ftp?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding not seeing the latest file, please check if the browser is not caching the files. Try again by deleting the browser cache.

> I also wonder, how can I explore the files that I uploaded to azure
>   website? In other web hosters, they usually have, file manager, or
>   using ftp. Btw, can we also access azure website root folders using
>   ftp?

If you deployed your application by using a publish profile file, open that file in a text editor. You will see FTP credentials in that file (see sample file contents below)

```
<publishData>   <publishProfile profileName="mytestwebsite - Web Deploy" publishMethod="MSDeploy" publishUrl="mytestwebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net:443" 
                  msdeploySite="mytestwebsite" userName="$mytestwebsite" userPWD="<cryptic password>" 
                  destinationAppUrl="http://mytestwebsite.azurewebsites.net" 
                  SQLServerDBConnectionString="" mySQLDBConnectionString="" hostingProviderForumLink="" controlPanelLink="http://windows.azure.com">
    <databases/>   </publishProfile>   <publishProfile profileName="mytestwebsite - FTP" publishMethod="FTP" publishUrl="ftp://waws-prod-blu-015.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot"

                  ftpPassiveMode="True" userName="mytestwebsite\$mytestwebsite" 
                  userPWD="<cryptic password>" 
                  destinationAppUrl="http://mytestwebsite.azurewebsites.net" 
                  SQLServerDBConnectionString="" mySQLDBConnectionString="" hostingProviderForumLink="" controlPanelLink="http://windows.azure.com">
    <databases/>   </publishProfile> </publishData>
```

You can download this file by visiting "Dashboard" section of your Azure Website in Azure Portal.

Comment: I have cleared the cache but it still does not work. I tried in Chrome, Firefox and IE. And all of them show the same :S

Comment: Can you try by restarting your website? Looking under "Tips and Tricks" section here (http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/bundling-and-minifying-in-asp-net-mvc), you may also see this behavior because bundles are cached.

Comment: I am sorry for asking too much. I have searched "how to restart azure website" but I think I could not find it. Can you please state it here.maybe as an answer so that I can mark?

Comment: UPDATE: I found it, it is in the portal haha. sorry. thanks for your help, lemme see it it works